# Include created folders In Project

Tags: c#, directory

I am working in an application that grapes real time data and stores them inside my project directory as excel sheets inside folders. My output folders are stored under bin\Debug. I click on show All to be able to see them. Is there a way to include these output folders programmatically?

Comment: Why do you want to include them?

Comment: to be able to see them without clicking on see all, there are lots of files that are not included in the project that shows up with my folders when I click on show All .. I do not want to see them !

Comment: All right, but I can't follow what benefit you're going to get by including them in your project. You can edit the .csproj file as stated in the answers, but I believe there can be better ways to do what you *really* want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you mean including the files in the project ? If so, you can do it by editing the project file. Project file (.csproj) is just a plain text file. First add a file and see how it affects the csproj file. After that you can programatically edit the csproj file to include the files you want.

Comment: is there any other way ? I do not want to play with the project xml format

Comment: you cannot include a file without editing the project file. You can only make the files in a specific folder visible by clicking "Show All files" button on solution explorer

Comment: Okay, how could I reference .csproj programmaticlly ? But this way all the files in bin\debug would be shown !! I do not want that to happen :/

Comment: First open an empty project and save it. copy the csproj file to a different location. After that add a new file to the project and save the project. Now consider the copy of the project file with the last one that you added a file. You can see how a project file is changed after you add a file. Now for every file you should do the same change on the csproj file. Just read it just like you are  reaidng a text file , edit it and close it.